# OpenGL Thread Conflict Detected

Tags: ios, multithreading, ios7, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

On iOS 7.1 (where `multiThreaded` on `EAGLContext` is introduced), I've been getting a lot of errors with "`OpenGL Thread Conflict Detected`".

I have set `multiThreaded = YES` on the context, but I still get the error. It's odd, because I get a lot of the same error outputted:

```
OpenGL Thread Conflict Detected
0x17022cd40
```

I think the hex is the thread ID - and it seems to be consistent.
Any ideas of why I'm getting this error outputted?

Comment: You aren't trying to access the EAGLContext from multiple threads, are you? I don't think this makes the EAGLContext threadsafe, it merely offloads some of the CPU-side instructions onto a helper thread to try to speed things up.

Comment: @BradLarson is right: all the `multiThreaded` property does is offload CPU work associated with OpenGL ES calls (e.g. formatting vertex buffers before uploading them to the GPU). To work with GL from multiple threads, you should use a separate context for each thread (and use a sharegroup if you want them to share resources). And if you're doing that, there's no point to setting `multiThreaded = YES` for the context that's on a background thread (and probably little for the one on the main thread, because you've offloaded all your CPU-heavy work to the background thread, right?).

Comment: I don't believe I'm using `EAGLContext` on multiple threads. I mean, every time it throws a warning, it prints a different address per run, but among multiple warnings, it's the same address (in completely different areas of my program).

@rickster I have offloaded my CPU-heavy work to a separate thread, and `EAGLContext` has its own thread as well (it was painful to get them to work properly, but they do).

The result doesn't cause the app to crash, and doesn't throw a warning all the time (though I've noticed it won't throw a warning when OGL breakpoints are disabled in XCode)

Answer (score -1):

OpenGL does not support (or at least supports it in very limited scenarios and not in the rendering part) multithreading.

It simply does not support it.

I am not aware of your particular usage or the iphone implementation but the library itself does not support it.

Try to see here.

http://www.equalizergraphics.com/documentation/parallelOpenGLFAQ.html

If you want to go for multithreading, in my experience, is to have a single thread handling the OpenGL library/rendering and one of more threads specialized in different scopes (path finding, AI, collision detection, you name it).

I hope this has helped.

Cheers
Maurizio

Comment: See [Apple's programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/ConcurrencyandOpenGLES/ConcurrencyandOpenGLES.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008793-CH409-SW2) for how multithreading with OpenGL ES works in iOS.